# Simultaneous access to different folders inside a ZIP file

Tags: c++, multithreading, zip, file-access

I need file access for reading and writing of the same ZIP archive from different threads at the same time.

Each thread has its own subdirectory inside the archive so there won't be conflicts, but I think the operating system doesn't care about that.

For ZIP operations I use libzip. How can I perform the accesses? Do I have to take care of something special?

I could unpack the archive on startup of the application and zip it on exit, but I'd prefer to operate on the archive directly, that's why I'm asking this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unpacking in parallel shouldn't be that difficult, but packing a file will definitely be non-trivial/

Unfortunately, the name of directories doesn't really matter if you are using the ZIP format - the header for where a file is stores is just a structure with the path and filename as one lump, and different directories don't exist within the zip-file.

The data is no better, as each file's data is just stored as one consecutive stream of data following the previous file, and before the next file.

One could of course make a zip-archive functionality where the compressed data is prepared, an once the data is complete, the space allocated and the header added to the directory - both of these under some sort of lock, and then the data can be written to the actual file without locks [although I'm not sure how well it works to write to different places in a file without using locks].

(It's quite well described in wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29), but it may not be entirely clear if you haven't studied these things what the consequences of the different data structures becomes)

Comment: +1. Updating *part of* a zip file in place is definitely non-trivial. About the only thing you can do is test whether the newly zipped data is *exactly* the size of the original chunk.